# ubicacion automatica en google maps luego de activar GPS, android studio con kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Estoy constuyendo una aplicacion en android studio con kotlin, mi duda es como hacer que despues de mostrar mi mensaje de activacion de gps automaticamente me enfoque a mi ubicacion actual:

```
private var isGPS:Boolean = false

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    mGPS = findViewById(R.id.icon_gps) //boton de gps

    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

    //Aqui estoy mostrando el mensaje de activacion de gps
    GpsUtils(this).turnGPSOn { isGPSEnable ->
        //Activar GPS
        isGPS = isGPSEnable
    }

}
```

Y tengo esta funcion para localizar mi ubicacion actual en la aplicacion:

```
private fun getDeviceLocation() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: obteniendo la ubicación actual de los dispositivos")
    mfusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

    try {
        mfusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener(this) { location ->
            if (location != null) {
                //lastLocation = location

                latitudOrigen = location.latitude
                longitudOrigen = location.longitude

                val miPosicion = LatLng(latitudOrigen,longitudOrigen)
                //val currentLatLong = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(miPosicion, DEFAULT_ZOOM))
            }
        }
    } catch (e: SecurityException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.message)
    }
}
```

mi funcion setUpMap()

```
private fun setUpMap() {

    //Analiza el permisos de acceso a la ubicación
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
        return
    }

    getDeviceLocation()

    map.isMyLocationEnabled = true //Marcador de ubicación actual
    map.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN //Tipo de mapa
    map.uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = false

}
```

mi funcion onMapReady()

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {

    map = googleMap
    setUpMap()

}
```

Estaba tratando de que al activar el gps con la alerta que muestro pero no logro hacerlo... por favor si alguien me podria ayudar

Comment: Si defini los permisos, el detalle es que cuando el gps no esta activado  normal muestra el mensaje y activo el gps, carga el mapa y aparece el punto azul, pero quiero que la funcion getDeviceLocation() se ejecute luego de activar el gps, no logro hacer eso, cuando el gps esta activado ahi normal se ejecuta la funcion getDeviceLocation()...

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se llama `onMapReady()` indica que el mapa ha sido inicializado por lo tanto aquí o dentro del método  `setUpMap()` el cual configura propiedades al mapa, puedes mover la cámara hacia el punto de geolocalización que desees:

```
val position = LatLng(latitudOrigen, longitudOrigen)
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 10f))
```

De acuerdo a tu código sería:

```
private fun setUpMap() {

    //Analiza el permisos de acceso a la ubicación
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
        return
    }

    if(isGPS){ //Si GPS es true obtiene la geolocalización
       getDeviceLocation()
    }

    //Mueve posición de cámara después de obtener punto origen.
    val position = LatLng(latitudOrigen, longitudOrigen)
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 10f))

    map.isMyLocationEnabled = true //Marcador de ubicación actual
    map.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN //Tipo de mapa
    map.uiSettings.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = false

}
```

Comment: Pero eso estoy poniendo en la funcion getDeviceLocation() osea cuando el GPS esta activado manualmente si funciona getDeviceLocation(), pero quiero que tambien se ejecute cuando me mande el mensaje  de activar gps en la alerta...

Comment: la idea es que cuando isGPS sea true se ejecute getDeviceLocation()

Comment: @Nik simplemente validalo, revisa la actualización, obviamente esto debe realizarse cuando se llama el método onMapReady()